# Flutter IOS FCM Push Notification - Device Token Not Working in Release Mode

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app in Flutter where I send notifications to IOS device with Firebase Cloud Messaging. Everything works correctly in the Android version of the same app. Everything seems to be fine in debug mode on the iOS version as well. However, when I try it on a physical IOS device, the token value usually comes as null in release mode.

As a result of my research, I made some changes and;

> 

```
My AppDelegate.swift file;

import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging


@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        }

       
    
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication,
        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data){Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
            print("Token: \(deviceToken)")
            super.application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
                
        }
}


My Info.plist file;

<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

It contains the relevant values. I don't know what I'm doing wrong with this. I would be grateful for any help.

Shortly: I'm trying to send FCM notifications using device token in Flutter. However, when I try it on a physical IOS device, the token value usually comes as null in release mode.

Comment: Did you correctly manage the permissions and make sure the device accepts the notification from your app ? Check out https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler if you havn't